# I have some confuse about javascript 3d library three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I want develop some web product with using javascript 3d library

like three.js

But I heared it would use WebGL tech,the problem is I want my product would also work fine on ipad or iphone,and some moblie device,I have try it,found the pad couldn't work the demo

So it has to use WebGL?Or I have some other javascript 3d library for substitute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL is not yet available on iOS Safari, though all signs point to it being enabled at some point in the near-ish future. It can currently be turned on with some private API hacks, and performance is actually quite good, but there are some serious bugs that need fixing before Apple will enable it for general use.

I wouldn't be surprised if it made it into iOS 6, but that's just pure speculation on my part.

Comment: can you tell me where I can find the "private API hacks"?I'm really curious about it

Comment: Check out http://benvanik.github.com/WebGLBrowser/ for a sample implementation. You have to have an iOS developer account to test it, since there's no way Apple would ever allow that into the store.